# Change Column width in component / Material Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Just wanted to ask an advice or tip. I have "DataTable" reusable component. But this component doesnt have any size/width Props. I need to add new prop called "columnWidth". What should I do for that? I have attached a code of the component that im working with. I need to make column width flexible depending on column content. Thank you for any help :D

```js
import React, { useEffect, FC, useState } from "react";
import { MDCDataTable } from "@material/data-table";
import "./index.css";
// import { MDCSelect } from '@material/select';

let dataTablesCounter = 1;

type DataTableProps = {
  columnWidth?: boolean;
  pagination?: boolean;
  count?: number;
  rowsNumber?: number;
  page?: number;
  next?: boolean;
  previous?: boolean;
  isLoading?: boolean;
  onNextClick?: () => void;
  onPreviosClick?: () => void;
};

export const DataTable: FC<DataTableProps> = ({
  columnWidth,
  children,
  pagination,
  count,
  rowsNumber,
  page,
  next,
  previous,
  onNextClick,
  onPreviosClick,
  isLoading,
}) => {
  const [id] = useState(`mdc-data-table-${dataTablesCounter++}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    const dataTable = new MDCDataTable(document.getElementById(id));

    if (isLoading) {
      dataTable.getDefaultFoundation().showProgress();
    } else {
      dataTable.getDefaultFoundation().hideProgress();
    }

    const thead = document.querySelector("thead");

    if (
      document.querySelector("tbody").scrollHeight <
      document.querySelector("table").offsetHeight
    ) {
      thead.style.padding = "0";
      thead.style.width = "100%";
    } else {
      thead.style.paddingRight = "17px";
      thead.style.width = "calc(100% - 17px)";
    }

    return () => {
      // dataTable.destroy();
    };
  }, [isLoading]);

  const getPaginationTotal = (): string => {
    let first = 1;
    let last = rowsNumber;
    let total = count;

    if (page > first) {
      first = 1 + rowsNumber;
      last = rowsNumber * page;
    }

    if (!next) {
      first = count - rowsNumber + 1;
      last = count;
    }

    if (total === 0) {
      first = 0;
    }

    const paginationTotal = `${first || 0}-${last || 0} из ${total || 0}`;

    return paginationTotal;
  };

  return (
    <div id={id} className="mdc-data-table">
      <div className="mdc-data-table__table-container">
        <table className="mdc-data-table__table">{children}</table>
      </div>
      {pagination && (
        <DataTablePagination
          onNextClick={onNextClick}
          onPreviosClick={onPreviosClick}
          paginationTotal={!isLoading && getPaginationTotal()}
          next={next}
          previous={previous}
        />
      )}
      <DataTableProgressIndicator />
    </div>
  );
};

export const DataTableHead: FC = ({ children }) => (
  <thead>
    <tr className="mdc-data-table__header-row">{children}</tr>
  </thead>
);

export const DataTableBody: FC = ({ children }) => (
  <tbody className="mdc-data-table__content">{children}</tbody>
);

export const DataTableHeadCell: FC = ({ children }) => (
  <th className="mdc-data-table__header-cell" role="columnheader">
    {children}
  </th>
);

type DataTableRowProps = {
  onClick?: () => void;
};

export const DataTableRow: FC<DataTableRowProps> = ({ children, onClick }) => {
  let className = "mdc-data-table__row";

  if (!!onClick) {
    className += " mdc-data-table__row--clickable";
  }

  return (
    <tr className={className} onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
    </tr>
  );
};

export const DataTableCell: FC = ({ children }) => (
  <td className="mdc-data-table__cell">{children}</td>
);

type DataTablePaginationProps = {
  onNextClick?: () => void;
  onPreviosClick?: () => void;
  paginationTotal?: string;
  next?: boolean;
  previous?: boolean;
};

export const DataTablePagination: FC<DataTablePaginationProps> = ({
  onNextClick,
  onPreviosClick,
  paginationTotal,
  next,
  previous,
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="mdc-data-table__pagination">
      <div className="mdc-data-table__pagination-trailing">
        <div className="mdc-data-table__pagination-navigation">
          <div className="mdc-data-table__pagination-total">
            {paginationTotal}
          </div>
          <button
            className="mdc-icon-button material-icons mdc-data-table__pagination-button"
            onClick={onPreviosClick}
            data-prev-page="true"
            disabled={!previous}
          >
            <div className="mdc-button__icon">chevron_left</div>
          </button>
          <button
            className="mdc-icon-button material-icons mdc-data-table__pagination-button"
            onClick={onNextClick}
            data-next-page="true"
            disabled={!next}
          >
            <div className="mdc-button__icon">chevron_right</div>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export const DataTableProgressIndicator = () => (
  <div className="mdc-data-table__progress-indicator">
    <div className="mdc-data-table__scrim"></div>
    <div
      className="mdc-linear-progress mdc-linear-progress--indeterminate mdc-data-table__linear-progress"
      role="progressbar"
      aria-label="Data is being loaded..."
    >
      <div className="mdc-linear-progress__buffer">
        <div className="mdc-linear-progress__buffer-bar"></div>
        <div className="mdc-linear-progress__buffer-dots"></div>
      </div>
      <div className="mdc-linear-progress__bar mdc-linear-progress__primary-bar">
        <span className="mdc-linear-progress__bar-inner"></span>
      </div>
      <div className="mdc-linear-progress__bar mdc-linear-progress__secondary-bar">
        <span className="mdc-linear-progress__bar-inner"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```